# generating a CSR file when there is no Certificate Authority through Keychain Access

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ssl, apple-push-notifications, push

I have been trying to get AWS SNS APNS to work for the past week and during the repeated process of generating the P12 file, I realized that in my system, I don't have a Certificate Authority. When I click on the csr file, the Certificate Assistant asks me to choose an "Issuing CA" but I don't see any CAs.

Could this have been the issue that AWS SNS APNS might not have worked? But I was able to still go through and create CSR file without having any CA. If this is indeed the reason why my AWS SNS APNS was not working, then, in terms of engineering schematics, how was I able to create a CSR file and does the CA affect my APNS settings?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post some more information regarding what error message you are seeing. It would really help if you enabled delivery status feature on sns console https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxHTXGC8711JNF/Using-the-Delivery-Status-feature-of-Amazon-SNS

Comment: I'm seeing an error. "status": "FAILURE".  "Endpoint is disabled". I have followed all the procedures required to make the p12 file etc. I know how it's done. I've done it many times. Any further suggestions now that I know the "Endpoint is disabled"? I tried to "undisable" it manually via console but couldn't do it. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One Link Hope Work For You :-

http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates